# Problems with typedef struct name

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct, typedef

Snippet 1:

```c
typedef struct list_s {
    int key;
    struct list_s *next;
}list_t;
```

Snippet 2:

```c
typedef struct list_s list_t;

struct list_s {
    int key;
    list_t *next;
};
```

I don't understand in snippet 1 or snippet 2 if the name of the struct is `list_t` or `list_s`. Usually I define a struct with name `other_t` as:

```c
typedef struct{
    int n;
}other_t;
```

Also in snippet 1 and snippet 2, what does the referencing to the struct with a pointer, which it is inside of meant to do? I mean :

`struct list_s *next;`

What is it's function?

Comment: the name of the struct is always `struct list_s`. In the last version, the struct has no name.

Comment: If you have a self-referential structure (if it contains one or more pointers to its own type), it must have a tag (e.g. `struct list_s`).  Lists are quintessential self-referential structures.  If your structure is not self-referential, the tag is optional.  If you don't have a tag, you must refer to the type name given by the `typedef`.  Note that the Linux kernel avoids typedefs for structure types, insisting that you always use `struct tag`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how one defines a struct type:

```c
struct Foo {
   ...
};
```

This can be used as follows:

```c
struct Foo foo;
struct Foo *p;
```

---

Using typedef, we can create an equivalent and compatible type without having to use `struct` everywhere.

```c
typedef struct {
   ...
} Foo;
```

This can be used as follows:

```c
Foo foo;
Foo *p;
```

---

When creating a self-referencing type (as snippets 1 and 2 do), you have to (directly or indirectly) use a struct type and not a "generic" type.

```c
struct Foo {
   struct Foo *next;
};
```

But nothing stops from also creating a "generic" type.

```c
typedef struct Foo Foo;
```

(They can even have the same name, as is the case in my example.)

Snippets 1 and 2 are equivalent, creating both a struct type (`struct list_s`) and an equivalent "generic" type (`list_t`).

Snippet 3 creates only a "generic" type (`other_t`).

---

The structure is probably used as the type for the nodes of a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). The pointer in one node would point to the next node in the list.

```
list_t *head         list_t anon0         list_t anon1         list_t anon2
+------------+       +------------+       +------------+       +------------+
|         ---------->| key:  ...  |   +-->| key:  ...  |   +-->| key:  ...  |
+------------+       +------------+   |   +------------+   |   +------------+
                     | next:   -------+   | next:   -------+   | next: NULL |
                     +------------+       +------------+       +------------+
```